# apollo benefits vs. redux with selectors

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

our team is using a hybrid of redux/sagas/apollo.

my question: why even use apollo to wrap components if we can

1. call fetch on the graphql endpoint
2. update our Redux store
3. use selectors to memoize and cache results

is there any other benefit besides code readability? (tying Apollo's graphql higher order component to the view)

Comment: `is there any other benefit besides code readability?` What other reason do you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things here. You can do what you described. In the end you can merge concepts together at your own will. There is no central authority deciding that you must keep concepts separate or together.

The question is really a team decision regarding how you collectively feel about redux's syntax and tradeoffs versus that of other state management. When you take that and compare it against your immediate needs then you ultimately must decide what the cost / benefit is.

Does your team feel ok about just using setState, bringing in [unstated](http://npm.im/unstated) only when needed? Do you move away from higher order components since Apollo [supports render props](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/whats-next-for-react-apollo-4d41ba12c2cb) which are more easily composed? Might you be better off just using [Apollo instead of redux](https://hackernoon.com/how-graphql-replaces-redux-3fff8289221d)? Do you want to [use Apollo for your remaining local state](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state)?

Naturally I am leading you to my opinions based on what the community is exploring at the moment. Should you rewrite your application to use a certain pattern? Only you and your team can evaluate your current pain points you are running into to determine that. As long as you continue to ask questions like this an attempt to compare it against your team's needs then you'll be on the right track.

Redux works great in apps, but many teams run into challenges when they seek to generalize components that rely on redux, favoring more composable state solutions. Naturally YMMV.

Comment: You're definitely right that it's a highly case-specific answer. I think I'll move us incrementally in this direction. The new Query and Mutation components are really compelling use cases for our app

Comment: Yes! And they were just released in Apollo 2.1 https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/introducing-react-apollo-2-1-c837cc23d926